# how to run iptables script in docker container by default

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, iptables

I have to start container with predefined iptables rules.

I have only script iptables.sh. How to use this script by default?

Comment: Is your intention to run `iptables` within the container or on the docker host?

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Docker has own networking implementation, so using iptables inside container can have no awaiting effect.

More about docker networking: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/